# Generic enum type in swagger api/website?

Tags: node.js, enums, swagger

I use an class `PageOptionsDto<T>` to get options of a table, for example which column is currently sorted. I also have an enum for each table that contains all column names for example:

```
enum PlayerColumns {
    NAME,
    HEIGHT,
    ...
}
```

The `PageOptionsDto<T>` has an property `orderColumn: T` that shows which column is currently oredered.

```
class PageOptionsDto<T> {

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    orderColumn: T;
}
```

This enables me to use this class for all my tables and just change the enum when using this class like `PageOptionsDto<PlayerColumns>`.

```
@Get()
async getPlayerTable(@Query() pageOptionsDto: PageOptionsDto<PlayerColumns>) {
    return ...
}
```

This all works greate but I have an problem when using this with swagger. How do I need to decorate this property so I can use it within the generated swagger website?

Currenty it won't show the property at all. I tryed to use `@IsEnum(T)` or `@ApiProperty({ enum: T, default: T[0]})` but that doesn't work. It would also be fine if it just shows an text input field so I can manual write the enum value.

Is something like that possible?